# UIManagedDocument does not update changes of relationships immediately

Tags: ios5, uimanageddocument

I'm using an UIManagedDocument in my project and have to change the relationship of existing objects.

All objects already exist in the database so I'm not dealing with the temporaryID/permanentID issue. I'm also almost using `updateChangeCount:` on my UIManagedDocument to *save* changes. So it shouldn't be an issue with the UIManagedDocument's usual suspects.

**Model:**

```
Company
   |-- Department
          |-- Employee
```

**Operation:**

Move a `Department` from one `Company` to another by calling `[aDepartment setCompany:newCompany]`.

**Situation 1 (succeeds):**

Execute a fetchRequest on entity `Department` calling `company = newCompany` returns the expected result.

**Situation 2 (fails):**

Execute a fetchRequest on entity `Employee` calling `department.company = newCompany` returns no result.

Situation 2 only succeeds after UIManagedDocument auto-saves.

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After dealing with this issue for quite a long time - unfortunately even Apple engineers weren't able to help - I was able to find a solution.

Calling `[myManagedDocument saveToURL:fileURL forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForOverwriting completionHandler:nil];` after changing the relationships solves the problem and returns the correct state immediately.

*Anyway, I was filling a bug report for this to get this done via `updateChangeCount:`.*

Answer (score 0):

the same issue.  I finally find a solution by saving both managedObjectContext and it's parent context.

```
NSError *error;
if ( ![self.fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext save:&error] ||![self.fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext.parentContext save:&error]) {
    //  .....
}
```